# TopShelf ConsoleHost exit on end

Tags: topshelf

I have a TopShelf based console/windows service app. I am using this as part of an automation script (in OctopusDeploy), by running the console app. However, the console app does not exit unless I press Ctrl-C. Is there a way to disable this final key press check?

Code :

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        HostFactory.Run(x =>
                {
                    x.Service<BatchJobService>(s =>
                                                   {
                                                       s.ConstructUsing(name => new BatchJobService());
                                                       s.WhenStarted((svc, hostControl) => svc.Start(hostControl));
                                                       s.WhenStopped((svc, hostControl) => svc.Stop(hostControl));
                                                   });
                    x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                    x.StartAutomatically();
                    x.SetDisplayName(serviceName);
                    x.SetServiceName(serviceName);
                });
    }
}

public class BatchJobService : ServiceControl
{
    private IDisposable host;

    public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        if (hostControl is ConsoleRunHost)
        {
            **// Code for console app....
            return true; // Upon exit, program does not terminate**
        }

        // Start code for service...

        return true;
    }

    public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
    {
        if (hostControl is ConsoleRunHost)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Stop code for service...
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: the same question. Has you found the way how to configure TopShelf do not wait for Ctrl+C?

Answer (score 0):

seems that it is not possible

I've checked topshelf source code ConsoleRunHost.cs and there is no way to avoid waiting for the `ManualResetEvent`:

```
try
{
    _log.Debug("Starting up as a console application");

    _exit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    _exitCode = TopshelfExitCode.Ok;

    Console.Title = _settings.DisplayName;
    Console.CancelKeyPress += HandleCancelKeyPress;

    if (!_serviceHandle.Start(this))
        throw new TopshelfException("The service failed to start (return false).");

    started = true;

    _log.InfoFormat("The {0} service is now running, press Control+C to exit.", _settings.ServiceName);

    _exit.WaitOne();
}
```

It is done by purpose I suppose since Windows service is long-running process and it has no sense to execute the Start method of the service and exit immediately.

However I'm testing how `docfx` tool is executed in the Azure build pipeline so I've created console that starts `docfx` and exits so there no long running process but there is a need in the windows service :)